# Two inertial frames (different angles)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, inertial-frames

> The motion of the earth relative to a star changes the angle at which the star is perceived. Consider to inertial frames of reference **I** and **I'**. I' moves with velocity **w** relative to I along the x-axis. Show that
>
> a) by looking at it in a non-relativistic way (classic) one can show the following correlation
>
> $\tan(\Delta\theta)=\frac{w\sin(\theta)}{c-w\cos(\theta)}$
>
> where $\theta$ is the angle for I and $\theta'$ the angle for I'. $\Delta\theta=\theta'-\theta$ is the perceived angle-difference.
>
> b) by looking at it in a relativistic way that
>
> $\cos(\theta)=\frac{\beta+\cos(\theta')}{1+\beta\cos(\theta')}$ and $\sin(\Delta\theta)=\sin(\theta)\frac{w}{c}$
>
> with $\beta=\frac{w}{c}$.

I've tried getting a visual aid for the problem by drawing all the information I got, but I still can't seem to find an approach to get to the desired equation. I've tried using the law of cosine, but it got me nowhere. Anyone got any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Are you confused on both parts of the problem, or just the relativistic parts?

Comment: a)Consider that the incoming ray of light is a particle with velocity $\mathbf{u}=-c\left(\cos\theta,\sin\theta\right)$ relatively to the frame $\mathbb{I}$. If $\mathbf{u}'=-u'\left(\cos\theta',\sin\theta'\right)$ is the velocity as seen from frame $\mathbb{I}^{\prime}$ then use the Newtonian addition of velocities $\mathbf{u}^{\prime}=\mathbf{u}-\mathbf{w}$. The magnitude $u^{\prime}$ will be not equal to $c$ since the case is nonrelativistic.

Comment: By the way I believe that the right equation in (a) must be $\tan\left(\theta'-\theta\right)=-\dfrac{w\sin\theta}{c+w\cos\theta}$. If rain drops fall normal to the ground, $\theta=\pi / 2$, then as you are driving you see the drops falling obliquely with $\theta'\le\pi/2=\theta$ that is $\tan\left(\theta'-\theta\right)\le 0$ while your equation gives $\ge 0$.

Comment: b)Consider that the incoming ray of light is a particle with velocity $\mathbf{u}=-c\left(\cos\theta,\sin\theta\right)$ relatively to the frame $\mathbb{I}$. If $\mathbf{u}'=-c\left(\cos\theta',\sin\theta'\right)$ is the velocity as seen from frame $\mathbb{I}^{\prime}$ then use relativistic addition of velocities $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{w}$ to find $\mathbf{u}'$. Note that all these describe the phenomenon of aberration.

Comment: @Frobenius Thanks for the fast help. I've tried doing your approach to get the equation but I can't seem to get $\tan(\theta'-\theta)=...$. I used an addition theorem for the tangent but couldn't get the desired equation. I'm assuming I would get to the same problem doing b).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint for (a) :

[image]
Use the Figure above to prove that :

\begin{equation}
\tan\left(\phi^{\prime}-\phi\right)=\dfrac{w\sin\phi}{c-w\cos\phi}=\dfrac{w\sin\theta}{c+w\cos\theta}\;=\;-\tan\left(\theta^{\prime}-\theta\right)
\tag{a-01}
\end{equation}
This explains why I find the last equality instead of the first as I post in one of my comments : we refer to different angles.

To give some further help, the vectors in the Figure are defined as follows using the $\:\phi=\pi-\theta\:$ angles

\begin{align}
\mathbf{u} & \equiv c\cdot\left(\cos\phi,\sin\phi\right)
\tag{a-02}\\
\mathbf{u}^{\prime} & \equiv u^{\prime}\cdot\left(\cos\phi^{\prime},\sin\phi^{\prime}\right) , \quad u^{\prime}=\|\mathbf{u}^{\prime}\| 
\tag{a-03}\\
\mathbf{w} & \equiv w\cdot\left(1,0\right) , \quad w=\|\mathbf{w}\| 
\tag{a-04}
\end{align}

and of course
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{u}^{\prime} =\mathbf{u} -\mathbf{w} 
\tag{a-05}
\end{equation}

---

Hint for (b) :

[image]

Use the Figure above to prove that :

\begin{align}
\cos\phi & =\dfrac{\beta+\cos\phi^{\prime}}{1+\beta\cos\phi^{\prime}}=\dfrac{\beta-\cos\theta^{\prime}}{1-\beta\cos\theta^{\prime}}=-\cos\theta \qquad \text{or}
\tag{b-01}\\
\cos\phi^{\prime} & =\dfrac{-\beta+\cos\phi}{1-\beta\cos\phi}=-\dfrac{\beta+\cos\theta}{1+\beta\cos\theta}=-\cos\theta^{\prime}
\tag{b-02}
\end{align}

To give some further help, the vectors in the Figure are defined as follows using the $\:\phi=\pi-\theta\:$ angles

\begin{align}
\mathbf{u} & \equiv c\cdot\left(\cos\phi,\sin\phi\right)
\tag{b-03}\\
\mathbf{u}^{\prime} & \equiv c\cdot\left(\cos\phi^{\prime},\sin\phi^{\prime}\right)
\tag{b-04}\\
\mathbf{w} & \equiv w\cdot\left(1,0\right) , \quad w=\|\mathbf{w}\| 
\tag{b-05}
\end{align}

and of course the velocity vector $\mathbf{u}^{\prime}$ is the relativistic sum of velocities $\mathbf{u}$ and $-\mathbf{w}$ :
\begin{align}
u_{x}^{\prime} & =\dfrac{u_{x}-w}{1-\dfrac{u_{x}w}{c^{2}}}
\tag{b-06x}\\
u_{y}^{\prime} & =\dfrac{u_{y}}{\gamma\left(1-\dfrac{u_{x}w}{c^{2}}\right)}
\tag{b-06y}\\
\gamma &=\left(1-\dfrac{w^{2}}{c^{2}}\right)^{-1/2}
\tag{b-06$\gamma$}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

a) Assume that light has to travel 1 m to reach the origin of the reference frame **I**, so it'll take $t=1/c $ seconds to reach.

Now, using trigonometry (the sine rule in the first equation), we get:

$$ \frac{\sin{\Delta\theta}}{\omega t} = \frac{\sin{\theta}}{ct} $$

$$ct\cos{\Delta\theta} = 1-{\omega t}\cos{\theta}$$

Dividing the first equation with the second,

$$ \tan{\Delta\theta} = \frac{\omega\sin{\theta}}{c(1-\frac{\omega}{c}\cos{\theta})} = \frac{\omega\sin{\theta}}{c-\omega\cos{\theta}} $$

Comment: @Arjit_Seth Sorry for my late response. Thanks, now I understand how to solve a). I've tried doing b) in a similar way, but I just can't seem to get it to work. I used the relativistic addition of velocities $d=\frac{a+b}{1+ab/c^2}$, but it got me nowhere.

Comment: I like Frobenius' approach to b). The thing about relativistic addition of velocities is that $ {\vec {u'}}$ is the velocity measured with respect to the inertial frame **I'**. However, as I perform the required calculation, I get: $ \cos\theta = \frac{-\beta + \cos\theta '}{1 - \beta\cos\theta '} $

Comment: Do you mind sharing the source of the question?

Comment: @Arjit_Seth It's from a german  textbook. I tried translating it as best as I could.

Comment: @Arjit_Seth :  I think that the result  $\cos\theta = \frac{-\beta + \cos\theta'}{1 - \beta\cos\theta'}$ you refer in your comment above is right and identical to my result , see last equality in equation (b-01) in my answer.